# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does this series converge

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$$

someone has told me that I have to apply Dirichlet's test but I don't know how to calculate the sum

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(n)\right|$$

Comment: See this question: [Computing the trigonometric sum $ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \cos(j) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059560/computing-the-trigonometric-sum-sum-j-1n-cosj)

Comment: @Winther How does that affect this question? Does it imply anything?

Comment: @VermillionAzure It implies convergence. [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) says that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges when $\sum b_n$ ($= \sum \cos(n)$) is bounded and $a_n$ is decreasing with $a_n\to 0$. The question linked to above (which is also done in the answer below) shows that the $\cos$-sum is bounded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the finite sums that you have to bound (it does not imply that the series converges). You have
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N\cos n\right|
& =\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \operatorname{Re}\,e^{in}\right|
=\left|\operatorname{Re}\,\sum_{n=1}^N e^{in}\right|
=\left|\operatorname{Re}\,\frac{e^{i}-e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^i}\right| \\[10pt]
& \leq\left|\frac{e^{i}-e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^i}\right|
\leq\frac2{|1-e^i|}
=\frac2{\sqrt{(1-\cos1)^2+\sin^21}}=\frac{\sqrt 2 }{\sqrt{1-\cos1}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Michael!

Comment: @Winther: nothing that three keystrokes cannot solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Multiply with $2\sin(\frac12)$ to get
\begin{align}
2\sin(\frac12)\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\cos n}{n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sin(n+\frac12)-\sin(n-\frac12)}{n}
\\
&=-\sin(\frac12)+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{\sin(n+\frac12)}{n(n+1)}+\frac{\sin(N+\frac12)}{N+1}
\end{align}
The sum in the middle is obviously absolutely convergent for $N\to\infty$, from where the convergence of the original series follows.