# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n)}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

this series converge

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n)}{n}$$

I think, that I have to apply the Abel's Rule but not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Almost (abstract) duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026584/convergence-of-sum-n-0-infty-frac-cosnn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Dirichlet test, if $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N\cos(2n)\right|<M$ is bounded, $\frac1n$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\cos(2n)\over n}$ converges.

You can calculate $\sum_{n=1}^N\cos(2n)$ by taking the real part of $\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2ni}$, a geometric sum.

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1